# VBA Assign value (only) to variable

Tags: vba, excel

I've hit a snag, and my searching hasn't helped so far.

I have a variant being passed into a function which I then intend to copy, perform some calculations, take another copy, perform some other calculations then compare the results of the two copies...

However, when I perform the calculations on one copy, the original variant is also manipulated... so after two copies, and two calculations I end up with 3 variants that are equal to each other and different to the original... Not what I intended.

I expect this is happening because when I use `NewVar = OldVar` I'm actually taking a reference to the original object. What I actually want, is to make an independent duplicate of the original object - i.e. copy the value of the variable similar to byval in a function delcaration.

My code is linked here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiPgb0BH-YZ_ga956eMmJbSdihGjyg.

If you put a break on line 67 of modMain, then watch `CutList(1).QTY` (the original variable), and `CutTrial.RemainingCuts(1).QTY` you'll see that both the QTY values decrement when you step through line 67... I want `CutList(1).QTY` to remain unchanged, and `CutTrial.RemainingCuts(1).QTY` to decement only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the actual code you're having problems with.

Comment: On line 54 of modMain you're setting CutTrial.RemainingCuts = cutList so they're both pointing to the same object. You'd have to create a new object at this point and assign it to CutTrail.RemainingCuts

Comment: @Amorpheuses - Yeah, this is the behaviour I'm seeing. I'll give your suggestion a shot - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the functions definition is as follows

Public function DoMagic(ByVal variable as something)

Don't use ByRef or as you found it will modify the reference.

If you are using an object, array or collection you will need to first copy it before using it.

Eg something like the following:

```
Public Function Clone() As Class1
Set Clone = New Class1
Clone.prop1 = prop1
Clone.PrivateThing = PrivateThing
End Function
```

Comment: This is only a solution if the passed `Variant` doesn't contain a reference type.

Comment: That still doesn't work with an `Object`.  `ByVal` with an `Object` passes the *pointer* by value.

Comment: Yes it needs to be cloned.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give that a shot and report back.

Comment: Remember that if you are writing a clone function, you need to clone any objects that are sub objects as well. Otherwise you'll have a new object, but it will include refs to your other objects members.

Comment: If that object is a variant, how do I clone it? the 'new' keyword doesn't work...